# my sub query return more than one value and I get error

Tags: sql

I get error "subquery returned more than one value" how to use join in my case to resolve this

```
SELECT fdCI.INITIALPROCESSINGUSER,
       fdCI.NEWUNDERWRITINGUSER,
       fdCI.ISSUEPOLICYUSER,
       fdR.REFERTOREASON,
       fdR.PUTONHOLDREASON,
       fdP.POLICYNUMBER,
       fdP.INSUREDNAME,
       p.WFSTATE,
       p.WFLOCKTYPE ,
       p.WFLOCKUSER,
       p.WORKFLOWID,
       p.WFWORKITEMID,
       p.WFROUTINGTICKETID,
       p.WFWORKSTEPNAME,
       p.WFSTEPENTRYTIME,
       p.WFPRIORSTEPNAME,
       fdp.OWNERNAME,
       fdR.REFERREDFROMUSERID,
       fdp.CLIENTCODE,
       p.WFFLOWENTRYTIME,
       c.ACL,
       fdp.PRODUCT,
       PLANCODE
FROM PINewBusiness p,
     CFPolicyCaseFolder c,
     FDRounting fdR,
     FDPolicyDetails fdP,
     FDCaseInformation fdCI
WHERE (p.WFWORKSTEPNAME = 'ApproveQuote'
       OR p.WFWORKSTEPNAME = 'ApprovalForm')
  AND fdCI.AUTHORIZATIONUSER IS NULL
  AND (fdR.NBAMOUNT <=
         (SELECT cul.NBLIMIT
          FROM FDNBUserAuthorization cua,
               FDNBAuthorizationLevel cul
          WHERE cua.NBAUTHORIZATIONID = cul.S_ROWID
            AND cua.USER_ID = 'obaidats'
            AND cul.NBTYPE= fdR.NBTYPE))
  AND (c.CASEFOLDERID = SUBSTRING(p.CFREPKEY, 9, LEN(p.CFREPKEY)))
  AND c.CASEFOLDERID=fdR.PARENT_CASEID
  AND c.CASEFOLDERID=fdP.PARENT_CASEID
  AND c.CASEFOLDERID=fdCI.PARENT_CASEID
  AND (fdP.RAPIDUND IS NULL
       OR fdP.RAPIDUND = 0)
```

Comment: Will selecting Max of subquery will not solve the issue?  `SELECT
  Max(cul.NBLIMIT)
FROM
  FDNBUserAuthorization cua,
  FDNBAuthorizationLevel cul
WHERE
  cua.NBAUTHORIZATIONID = cul.S_ROWID
  AND cua.USER_ID = 'obaidats'
  AND cul.NBTYPE = fdR.NBTYPE`

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `ON`.  This is the 21st century.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the output of your below sub query?

```
SELECT cul.NBLIMIT
FROM FDNBUserAuthorization cua,
FDNBAuthorizationLevel cul
WHERE cua.NBAUTHORIZATIONID = cul.S_ROWID
AND cua.USER_ID = 'obaidats'
AND cul.NBTYPE= fdR.NBTYPE
```

Its returning multiple rows for sure as the ERROR message is a self explanatory. Now check what values are returning in the column - cul.NBLIMIT? If all values are same and you can keep any of them, just select TOP 1 as below-

Note:

> TOP 1 is applicable for MSSQL Server,
>   For MySQL and Oracle, you can use - LIMIT 1

```
SELECT TOP 1 cul.NBLIMIT
FROM FDNBUserAuthorization cua,
FDNBAuthorizationLevel cul
WHERE cua.NBAUTHORIZATIONID = cul.S_ROWID
AND cua.USER_ID = 'obaidats'
AND cul.NBTYPE= fdR.NBTYPE
```

But if the values are different in different rows, you need to first define that how you would like to convert them into one value by applying aggregator like - SUM, MAX, MIN as below-

```
SELECT MAX(cul.NBLIMIT)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

For this Subquery you should be sure that it's not returning more than one row:

```
SELECT cul.NBLIMIT
          FROM FDNBUserAuthorization cua,
               FDNBAuthorizationLevel cul
          WHERE cua.NBAUTHORIZATIONID = cul.S_ROWID
            AND cua.USER_ID = 'obaidats'
            AND cul.NBTYPE= fdR.NBTYPE
```

Two options to technically fix this

```
SELECT **MIN/MAX**(cul.NBLIMIT)
          FROM FDNBUserAuthorization cua,
               FDNBAuthorizationLevel cul
          WHERE cua.NBAUTHORIZATIONID = cul.S_ROWID
            AND cua.USER_ID = 'obaidats'
            AND cul.NBTYPE= fdR.NBTYPE
```

OR

```
SELECT cul.NBLIMIT
          FROM FDNBUserAuthorization cua,
               FDNBAuthorizationLevel cul
          WHERE cua.NBAUTHORIZATIONID = cul.S_ROWID
            AND cua.USER_ID = 'obaidats'
            AND cul.NBTYPE= fdR.NBTYPE
             WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```